# invalid dropzone element with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, dropzone.js

Getting "invalid dropzone element". I put

```
 var Dropzone = require('react-dropzone');
```

in my webpack.config.js file which I thought would enable the Dropzone element.

Here's what's inside my javscript file, taken from the Github example:

```
var DropzoneFileUploader = React.createClass({
    onDrop: function(files){
        files.forEach((file)=> {

            console.log(file);

        });
    },

    render: function () {
      return (
          <div>
            <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
              <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
            </Dropzone>
          </div>
      );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<DropzoneFileUploader />,
                document.getElementById('container'));
```

The error is when I use the `<Dropzone>` tag. I have also included the dropzone script in my html file. I'm not able to put the require module inside the javascript file because it would give me the error "require is not defined"

```
    <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import react-dropzone inside your javascript file, not inside your webpack config.

Are you javascript was builded by webpack? Or you included it as is?

`require` is a function which provided by webpack. If you build file with webpack you will not get error.

Comment: Yes I am using webpack to build my javascript file. Even when I import react-dropzone inside it I still get require is not defined. I've even put "resolve: {
  root: [
   path.resolve('./node_modules')
  ]
 } in my webpack config

Comment: @user3226932 Can you provide your config?